# Splicing a turbo charger to another c type cord

Tags: power-supply

I have a charger That came from a T-Mobile wifi tower. It is a c type connection that is hardwired to the plug in. I broke the c type connector off. I have another c type cord that I want to splice it too. My phone, a Motorola Moto G recognizes the tmobile cord as a "Turbo charger" and charges pretty fast on it. I cut open both cords. The Tmobile cord has 3 corts inside; black, white and gray. The regular c type has four wires;black, white,green and red. Which wires should be spliced together?

Answer (score 0):

The colors themselves are not important but indicate that they are not comptible.

The 3-wire cable is likely has no USB data but uses USB power with Power Delivery.

The 4-wire cable likely has USB power and data without Power Delivery.